# PHP redirect not working in IE, Firefox after form

Tags: php, redirect

I am trying to redirect users to different URLs depending upon a form selection. But the code is only working in Chrome and not IE or FF. The latter just return a blank page. The 'trial' variable is to check if they are eligible to proceed

My code is:

```
<?php
    if ($_POST['trial'] == 'TRUE') {
    if ($_POST['submit1'] == 'x') { header('Location:http://www.url1.com'); }
    if ($_POST['submit2'] == 'y') { header('Location:http://www.url2.com'); }
    }  
if (!isset($_POST['trial'])) {
include 'error.php';}
?>
```

I can't see where the problem lies?

Can anyone help?

Thanks TT

Comment: well just put `if ($_POST['submit2'] == 'y') { header('Location:http://www.url2.com'); }` in your page, and check if it redirection works or not. Redirection works fine in FF in mine
`

Comment: keep in mind that header must be the first ouput on the page

Comment: *Always* `exit;` after performing a header redirect http://thedailywtf.com/Articles/WellIntentioned-Destruction.aspx

Comment: Are you doing anything before that - header won't work if you've outputted anything at all first. Also, should be a space:    header('Location: http://www.url2.com');

Comment: @phil That is HILARIOUS ... love it

Answer (score 5):

Stop the script after sending redirection. Also mind the **SPACE** after `Location:`.

```
header ('Location: http://www.url1.com');
exit ();
```

Comment: Hi - Thanks. Did both of these. It now works in FF but not IE8.

Comment: The problem under IE can be (between many other things) that your `<form>` has no explicit `action` property.

Answer (score 1):

Are your submit buttons by any chance `<button>`? IE handles buttons quite differently, it submits the actual content of the button opposed to the value="" attribute.

Answer (score 0):

why don't you put this in your submit.php and see what IE is posting, it may send something different after all:

```
<pre><?php
var_dump($_POST);
```

Comment: I tried this and there were all my variables.IE is the only browser not working with this. I've decided to dump this for now and try a different method.

Comment: If IE will not post your variables then the problem certainly lies in your `<form>` code. Give that part of your sorce to your question so we can pinpoint the problem.