# PHP Code working in Chrome but not Firefox

Tags: php, redirect, location

```
$redirect = $_GET["a"];

if(isset($redirect))
{
    $get302 = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("SELECT url, redirect from urls where redirect = '" . $redirect . "'"));
    header("Location: " . $get302["url"]);
    exit();
}
```

As far as I know this code works fine logically. (Made sure there won't be any loops so I put an isset(). But for some reason firefox doesn't like it and I'm not sure how I can edit the code much more for it to work.

Edit: I should also note that the code does work fine on Google Chrome.

Comment: and the error you're getting is...

Comment: Well then there has to be a reason why Chrome can load the code fine and Firefox can't.

Comment: Does `$get302["url"]` contain an absolute URI?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [php redirect not working in IE Firefox after form](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5418096/php-redirect-not-working-in-ie-firefox-after-form)

Comment: @PeeHaa If $redirect can be found in the mysql database then it will at least have http:// or https://

Comment: In that case [RTFM](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) about the `header()` function. And what to do after it. Hint :)

Comment: @PeeHaa If you mean adding TRUE,302 after $get302["url"] then I just tried that and it didn't change anything in Firefox. (Sorry if I'm misunderstanding what you're saying)

Answer (score 1):

You should check [this SO article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5418096/php-redirect-not-working-in-ie-firefox-after-form).

The discussion there recommends that you `exit;` after issuing a header redirect.

Comment: I just checked that and I tried, still doesn't work. Here's what the new code looks like: (on the OP)

Answer (score 0):

Firefox more closely follows web standards, I'm guessing you have a relative uri that you're passing to redirect, not allowed.

Comment: I am not using any relative URIs. If anything the page is failing to load even when there is no GET in the url. (The page will fail to load even if its http://localhost)